# How to find that one matrix is submatrix of the other in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to find that a given matrix is a sub matrix of the other.

I have tried below piece of code but I am not sure that it would work:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - b.length + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length - b[0].length + 1; j++) {
        boolean submatrix = true; // at start we assume we have a submatrix
        for (int k = 0; k < b.length; ++k) {
            for (int l = 0; l < b[0].length; ++l) {
                if (a[i + k][j + l] == b[k][l]) {
                    Console.WriteLine("a[" + (i + k) + "][" + (j + l) + "] = b[" + k + "][" + l + "]");
                } else {
                    submatrix = false; // we found inequality, so it's not a submatrix
                }
            }
        }
        if (submatrix) {
            Console.WriteLine("Found subatrix at " + i + "," + j + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest??

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: You're not sure that it would work? You mean you haven't checked?

Comment: Why don't you try running the program and tell us if it works or not.  If it doesn't, explain why.  (Does it result in an error, not expected output (if so, please provided both expected and actual output)).

Comment: Start by reviewing Efficient Processing for Binary Submatrix Matching (http://thescipub.com/pdf/10.3844/ajassp.2009.78.88)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested method is correct, there are only a few syntax and control flow issues which I've fixed.

It is important to point out that this method is only useful for detecting a submatrix of a **2D matrix**, not any dimension matrix.

I assumed the datatype is a jagged array of `int`, though it can easily be changed.

```
private static bool IsSubMatrix(int[][] a, int[][] b)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < a.Length - b.Length + 1; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < a[0].Length - b[0].Length + 1; j++)
         {
              bool found = true;
              for (int k = 0; k < b.Length; ++k)
              {
                  for (int l = 0; l < b[0].Length; ++l)
                  {
                      if (a[i + k][j + l] != b[k][l])
                      {
                          found = false;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  if (!found) break;
              }
              if (found) return true;
          }
      }          
      return false;
 }
```

This is probably also not the fastest implementation.

Comment: The first `continue` (in the `l` loop) should be a `break`.

Comment: @Rotem:- I have also pasted the answer to my own question...I was getting the desired result for this one...but I wanted to simplify it....Please suggest